# Suitable technology for scalable cloud app with API for approx 100K requests per minute

Tags: .net, database, azure, api, scalable

I'm C# dev with focus on mobile apps and desktop, I've never done anything which includes cloud, cloud apps, web or cloud API (other than WCF). What is latest (LTS) technology for simple API with its own database (one or two tables at most) ? Majority of the requests wouldn't need write access to DB. Could you hold data in memory like cache and synchro it once in a while ? What is the best approach to achieve this ? Scalability is a must as it should be able to serve approx 100K requests per minute in peek. Preferably it should be something from Azure and .NET, but its so huge that I don't know whats best combination for it.

Comment: You can develop a simple .net webapi for this purpose for which microsoft provides alot of good boilerplate code samples in VS code and VS. After you are happy with your local working solution you can host it in Azure App service and scale it as you like. Azure provides really handy tools to assess the requests, volume and scalability of your app.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question. There are a *lot* of technologies and features that can be used. It's not a question of whether to use MVC, Web API or minimal APIs